# How do you have traefik handle HTTP redirects before an HTTPS redirect?

Tags: traefik

The company I work for is currently using nginx as a reverse proxy.
It works good for us, but I'm looking into switching some of our servers from using VMs, to using docker containers, and would like to switch to using traefik.

I've been playing around with traefik, and while it seems to work good with containers, I'm having trouble replicating some of our existing nginx functionality.

Currently, our nginx config looks like this:

```
if request is coming in on port 80
    if HOST field says "domainA.com"
        redirect to http://someplace.com
    if HOST field says "domainB.com"
        redirect to http://someplace.com
    otherwise
        redirect this HTTP request to HTTPS
```

Without the HTTPS redirect, this config seems to work great:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]
[file]

[frontends]
    [frontends.frontend1]
    backend = "backend1"
        [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
        rule = "Host:domainA.com,domainB.com"

[backends]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
    url = "http://someplace.com"
```

The problem is, when I add the recommended way to add the HTTPS redirect, it takes precedence, which breaks the above HTTP redirects:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"

    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

Is there a proper way to do this so that the HTTPS redirect only happens if other HTTP rules don't match?

Update:

I seem to be getting closer. Instead of the [entryPoints] section, if I add this:

```
[frontends.frontend2]
backend = "backend2"
    [frontends.frontend2.headers]
    SSLRedirect = true
```

It almost works. The problem is, I need to point this to a specific backend, instead of just sending it back to the https entrypoint to go through LetsEncrypt (if there's no cert), and get routed from there.

Maybe if the backend definition could send the traffic back to an entry point, that might work, but as far as I can tell from reading the docs, that's not possible.